# How to configure product box/packaging options with its respective price in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Hi we are using magento for a wholesale site, in which every product can be ordered in two ways:
 
1)carton(small-box)
 
2)Pallet(larger-one)

Now as per magento rules we achieved the same by creating a bundle product for each product, but in doing so we need to add 3-products for a single product, also the SKU is actually the same for all!

Is there any better solution to this other than bundle?

I tried with the configurable option too, but same problem of adding 3-products for a single product.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a bundle product is the correct way to deal with this. In your case, the carton and the pallet are two separate products (from Magento's point of view).

Comment: Hi, is there any documentation regarding same from the magento itself? so that i can make it's reference to my client, or else it will be taken as our inefficiency in developing.Thanks.

Comment: I didn't find any direct documentation on that. You can try to contact Magento with the question, if you need an answer for the client.